# Spring interceptor is not operate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am a college student working on a personal project. While working on the project, I encountered an issue where the Spring interceptor is not functioning properly. I have a question regarding this matter.

#### LoginInterceptor.java

```
package Alchole_free.Cockpybara.interceptor;

import Alchole_free.Cockpybara.constant.SessionLoginConst;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


@Slf4j
@Component
public class LoginInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler) throws Exception {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        log.info("session = {}", session);
        if (session == null || session.getAttribute(SessionLoginConst.LOGIN_MEMBER) == null) {
            log.info("unauthorized user");
            response.sendRedirect("/login");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

#### WebConfig.java

```
package Alchole_free.Cockpybara.config;

import Alchole_free.Cockpybara.interceptor.LoginInterceptor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

//@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final LoginInterceptor loginInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(loginInterceptor)
                .addPathPatterns("/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/join", "/login");
    }
}
```

#### Test Interceptor By Postman

**send any request to api**
[request to api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc6VL.png)

**result log**
[result log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b4eI.png)
can check interceptor is not worked

I was able to confirm that the interceptor and config are being registered as beans when executing the below test code.

#### Test code to check Beans

```
package Alchole_free;

import Alchole_free.Cockpybara.CockpybaraApplication;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(classes = CockpybaraApplication.class)
public class ApplicationContextInfoTest {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ac;

    @Test
    void findAllBean(){
        String[] beanDefinitionNames = ac.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String beanDefinitionName : beanDefinitionNames) {
            Object bean = ac.getBean(beanDefinitionName);
            System.out.println(bean);
        }
    }
}
```

**result**
[result log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YTRT.png)

I'm really unsure what the issue is. Please help me out!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.